# How to equals correctly a Variable with String in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I will use the Data from GET Request in Angular.js, like below.

```
    var app = angular.module('Saidas',[]);
    app.controller('Status', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
        $interval(function(){
            var request = $http.get('/SaidasSite');    
            request.success(function(data) {
                if (data='QTD1LEDON') {
                    $('#QTD1LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on');
                } else (data='QTDLEDOFF'){
                    $('#QTD1LAMP').bootstrapToggle('off');
                } else (data='QTD2LEDON'){
                    $('#QTD2LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on')
                } else { $('#QTD1LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on'); }
            })
            .error(function(data){
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
        }, 5000);
```

When i receive "QTD1LEDON", i will toogle a Button in my Code to "ON", when i receive QT1LEDOFF, i will toogle to "OFF". But when i do this code, the comparison always a "QTD1LEDON". What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Did you check what the 'data' parameter in success callback is returning?

Comment: Check the data like Jannu said. console.log(data)
why don't you use an ng-model instead?
Replace the first 2 else by else if.

Comment: you are comparing right ? So why the single `=` (this is assignment operator). For comparing use `==`(comparison operator). Try & let me know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an assigment instead a comparison. So, in the first *if* you are giving to data the value 'QTD1LEDON', and always is true.

You need to fix:

```
if (data='QTD1LEDON') {
```

with:

```
if (data==='QTD1LEDON') {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `===` for comparison, not `=` which is for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you make a comparison using `===` or `==`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

In your code you use `=`, which simply assigns a value to your `data` variable, meaning the condition always evaluates as truthy: 
`if (data='QTD1LEDON') {`

You need to use `==` or `===` and it will behave as you are expecting:

`if (data === 'QTD1LEDON') {`

Answer (score 0):

You are making assignments instead of comparisons and you also have 3 `else` statements where you should only have 1, so you should have something like

```
if (data === 'QTD1LEDON') {
     ...
} else if (data === 'QTDLEDOFF') {
     ...
} else if (data === 'QTD2LEDON') {
     ...
} else { ... }
```